# Query related to file writing in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'd like to know the difference between

```
local log_line; log_line=$(basename $0)
echo "$(date --rfc-3339=seconds) $log_line.info: $*" >>"$LOG_FILE" >&2 echo "$log_line.info: $*"
```

and

```
local log_line; log_line=$(basename $0)
echo "$(date --rfc-3339=seconds) $log_line.info: $*" >>"$LOG_FILE"
>&2 echo "$log_line.info: $*".
```

Why only the first one logs into declared file and not the second one

Comment: Um, isn't it the other way around? [In my test](https://onlinegdb.com/VIdmNdGc3q), only the second command writes to the file. Please have a look at [How to create a **Minimal**, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We don't need all those variables and so on; asking about something like `echo a >>file >&2 echo b` is easier.

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: [Order of redirections](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/37660/187122)